# How is the matrix reordered for a heatmap in R? How to reorder the actual matrix with values in the same way so it corresponds to the heatmap?

Tags: r, matrix, heatmap

When plotting a heatmap in R from a given matrix, it automatically reorders the rows and columns so the visualization is easier.

I was wondering how it does that so that I can reorder the actual data frame itself with the numbers. (so the matrix with the numbers is reordered)

I hope this makes sense.

Thanks

Comment: It's easier to help you and give specific advice if you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data and the function call you are using. I assume you've at least read the `?heatmap` help page to see read how reordering is done.

Comment: which heatmap function are you currently using?? In general you can 'scale' your data by row or column or even both. That's how the function reorder your data. But you can treat your data using Pearson correlation or euclidean

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the clustered orders by assigning your heatmap to an object rather than plotting it. Let's try with some random data:

```
set.seed(111)
mat <- matrix(rnorm(40), nrow=4)
h <- heatmap(mat)
```

Now the orders are stored in `rowInd` and `colInd`.

```
> h$rowInd
[1] 3 2 4 1
```

So, to get the reordered matrix, use indices with the original matrix:

```
mat[h$rowInd, h$colInd]
```

Note: you can use for example `mat[rev(h$rowInd), ]` if you want to reverse the order of the rows.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `heatmap.2` function in `gplots` package, fortunately this can be done more easily. First load in some test data:

```
my.image <-
structure(c(0.284887135194186, 0.0266252817250525, 0.348431746937973, 
0.746492464670314, 0.267235059081902, 0.0209642747046111, 0.378676942016667, 
0.607990837304665, 0.312847060269367, 0.612395191587952, 0.483024535963144, 
0.564162902506238, 0.128115012083734, 0.548085047655703, 0.614939304016718, 
0.51253667320726, 0.591278116015954, 0.395201893060755, 0.682934039875973, 
0.416956130236154, 0.677632422556141, 0.385639902518959, 0.692257324851365, 
0.358990284723972, 0.224435642972774, 0.376108601670825, 0.717444067668913, 
0.308920663224123, 0.149392034309146, 0.399379225875787, 0.158378066789988, 
0.0536693928847938, 0.049487973904056, 0.54274177846382, 0.0398607307385965
), .Dim = c(7L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(c("row1", "row2", "row3", 
"row4", "row5", "row6", "row7"), c("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", 
"col5")))
```

Then plot the heatmap, preserving the row and column order:

```
library(gplots)
heatmap.2(my.image, density.info="none", trace="none", dendrogram='none', 
     Rowv=FALSE, Colv=FALSE)
```

The image looks like this:

[image]

This article by Sebastian Rashka is also very helpful for producing heatmaps that actually look good: http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/heatmaps_in_r.html